# Why is this function showing segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

This is a function to insert into a sorted linked list but it is showing segmentation fault (SIGSEGV)

```
void sortedInsert(struct node **head_ref, int data) {
    struct node *new_node, *prev, *current;
    new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->data > data) {
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
        return;
    }
    current = *head_ref;
    prev = NULL;
    while (current->data < data && current != NULL) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    prev->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = current;
}
```

Comment: Most likely because it has one or more bugs, which you can find using a debugger.

Comment: Don't malloc in C++.

Comment: `while(current->data<data&&current!=NULL)` should be `while(current!=NULL && current->data < data)`

Comment: this is a run time question, but the posted code does not compile.  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: what is the definition of: `struct node`?

Comment: this statement: ` while(current->data<data&&current!=NULL)` is dereferencing off of `current` without first assuring that `current` does not contain NULL.  Suggest reversing the order of the expressions around the '&&' operator

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*`, so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, is error prone, and makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) insert appropriate horizontal spacing, after commas, after semicolons (except end of line), inside parens, around logic operators, around math operators, etc. 3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: struct node{int data;struct node *next;};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the segmentation fault here is because of the statement:

```
while(current->data<data&&current!=NULL)
    {
        prev=current;
        current=current->next;
    }
```

The current pointer here is being dereferenced without being checked for NULL. You should try changing the condition to `while(current && current->data<data)` so that the pointer gets checked for NULL before being dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is here: `while (current->data < data && current != NULL)`. The pointer must be checked against `NULL` **before** it is dereferenced:

```
while (current != NULL && current->data < data)
```

Note that this function can be simplified with a single loop:

```
void sortedInsert(struct node **head_ref, int data) {
    struct node *new_node;
    while (*head_ref && (*head_ref)->data <= data) {
        head_ref = &(*head_ref)->next;
    }
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        /* handle the error */
        ...
    } else {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this statement fails on the first iteration:

```
while(current->data<data&&current!=NULL)
```

then this statement:

```
prev->next=new_node;
```

will be accessing an offset from address 0 which will almost always result in a seg fault event.